# My Telegram videos goes as files instead of media

Tags: video, telegram-messenger

When I receive a video on Telegram it's playable and I can see instantly a thumb of it.

However, when I send a video it goes as a file and not a media, showing only the file name.

Yes, I do press to send a media instead of file, but it always happens, both on mobile and desktop pc.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is, instead of directly sending the Video file, I open it first on my phone. I use "open with gallery." So it plays in gallery.

Then at the bottom there are options like "send" , "delete" etc. So I use send and then select telegram and it opens the app and then I select the chat.